# Can I use theHTML input tag (with JS) instead of the JavaScript prompt to record variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I want to be able to write an input tag from HTML, and do something with JavaScript (or jQuery).

So, when the user presses `submit`, it creates a cookie or makes a variable. That way they can enter their name in **without** typing it in an ugly user prompt box.

Comment: Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: Time to introduce yourself to HTML Forms! http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp

Comment: @crc442 w3schools is just the worse docs / literature resource you can find out there...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I know, but OP seems to have just started and I didn't want to overwhelm him with something like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms

Comment: The general answer to your general question is "Yes, you can get variable from HTML input, and it's easy to google how to do it.".